Can all elements of the completion of a filtration be represented as union of an element of the original filtration and a null set?
Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P,(\mathcal{F}(t)))$ be a filtered probability space and $\mathcal{N}=\{M\subset F\in\mathcal{F}:~P(F)=0\}$. Then the completion $(\mathcal{F}_0(t))$ of $(\mathcal{F}(t))$ is given by $\mathcal{F}_0(t)=\sigma(\mathcal{F}(t),\mathcal{N})$.
I am unsure whether in general it is true that any element $A_0\in\mathcal{F}_0(t)$ can be written as
$$
A_0=A\cup N
$$
with $A\in\mathcal{F}(t)$ and $N\in\mathcal{N}$? If so, how can this be proved?

Not exactly. You also need to add null set subtractions (complements $N^{c}$) and their combinations with unions, i.e.
$$
A_{0}= (A \cup N_{1}) \cap N_{2}^{c}.
$$
Some of those sets from completed $\sigma$-algebra may not be possible to represent as a union, for example in the case of $\mathcal{F} = \left\{ \emptyset, \Omega \right\}$ we will have $N^{c} \in \mathcal{F}_{0}, N^{c} \notin \mathcal{N}$.
The unions of those sets will have the same form, so they will form a $\sigma$-algebra, so every set from $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ can be represented this way.

Thank you very much, this completely answers my question! Just for others to avoid any misunderstanding, I believe in your example, it should be $\mathcal{F}(t)$ to avoid confusion with the underlying sigma-algebra of the probability space (I had mistyped it in parts of my original question as well).
